# Online Accounts Hang after fresh install

Tags: 18.04, online-accounts, ms-exchange

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 on an HP x360 Spectre, Google, Microsoft, Facebook... all hang when clicked.  Actually after several minutes, the Google window asked for the account name, but then returned after a few more minutes with "something went wrong...".  Ubuntu Single Sign-On works.  I had been using these accounts and a Microsoft Exchange account on this machine using an old install of 18.04.  No problems with the accounts until now.  The copy of Ubuntu 18.04.2 was just downloaded today.  In case there is any confusion, I'm talking about going into Settings, and then Online Accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I fixed my problem by re-booting my cable modem/wifi.  It didn't seem like it could be the problem since I was able to access the internet for other activities such as accessing this web page, watching youtube videos, etc.  However, since some other person mentioned that going from a wifi connection to a hard-wired connection on his computer fixed his problem, I thought it might still be something to do with my internet access.  Actually, I think it was more likely something to do with the router.  Anyway, thank you to anyone that read my question and gave it some thought.  Perhaps someone else will run up against this and my solution might help.